# Squeeze table inside container (truncating column)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I have a table that I need to squeeze in a small container:

```
<table class="table table-condensed list-table small">
    <tr class="active">
        <th class="col-md-1">ABC</th>
        <th class="col-md-6">Domain</th>
        <th class="col-md-5">IP</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col-md-1">2.23</td>
        <td class="domain-col col-md-6">
            kjshf78fiels9.domain-my-domain.com
        </td>
        <td class="col-md-5">127.100.100.255</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The full scenario here:
http://jsfiddle.net/j8WvF/1/

To be able to do this I want to truncate the *Domain* column (overflow and wrapping should be taken care of by the `.domain-col` class).

### The problem

I can't make the cell narrower than it's content.

### Ideal solution

The two columns *ABC* and *IP* to expand to the full width of their content, while the *Domain* column to take the remaining space (and all the table to shrink to the size of it's container.

Note: the container is resizable, so it would be best if the table would expand to fill the whole container even when the container gets larger.

### Good enough solution

Assign width percentage (Bootstrap classes `col-md-*`) to each column, and they would strictly respect that width.

Comment: Already seen this, not helping: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636327/auto-resize-columns-in-a-table-within-a-div-container-html

Comment: Some what I got this http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/j8WvF/5/

Comment: If the table would span over the whole container would be great (doesn't work in Ff, btw)

Comment: See my update. You should set up a bounty and a more detailed question if you have multiple wishes targeting your needs only. SO is not an consultancy service :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you cant shrink `.domain-col` is caused by your CSS selector, Not

```
.domain-col {
```

but

```css
td.domain-col {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: 90px;
}
```

forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/BafF5/**

---

**Update** : To achieve what you want in your *update* :

```css
td.domain-col {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: 90px;
}
td.col-md-1, td.col-md-5 {
   width:1%;
}
```

**new** forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/R867n/**

550px :

[image]

250px :

[image]

Comment: Why does this happen?

Comment: Updated my question. (Also updated your solution to stretch nicely: http://jsfiddle.net/BafF5/9) - awesome work, thank you!

Comment: Perfect. The ideal solution. Thanks!